# How to load saved image in swift on ios simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, swift

I save an image using this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.png"];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Then, I exit the app in the simulator. Then I attempt to load the image with this:

```
 let imageName = "Image.png"
 let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
 i1.image = image
```

I can think of two reasons the image does not load:

1. Exiting the app in the simulator is causing it to be uninstalled.
2. I am not getting the paths correct in swift vs. obj-c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIImage(named: imageName)` does not fetch an image from the Documents directory. It fetches an image only from the inside of the app itself (the app bundle), which is a very different place. The inside of the app bundle is not where you saved it (nor is it possible to save anything there), so naturally `UIImage(named: imageName)` comes up empty-handed. It can't find the file, for the simple reason that the file is not there to be found.

If you want to read the image file from the Documents directory, read it exactly the same way you wrote it: by forming the file path (or file URL) and reading it as data from disk. For example, having formed the file path, call UIImage's `init(contentsOfFile:)`.